# Extrude a face then cancel with right click create an edge?

Tags: transforms, faces, extrude

I'm new to blender, and until now there is something that is not clear to me:

I've noticed a while ago that sometimes when I click on a face then click <kbd>G</kbd> shortcut to move that face, it's looks like reacting if I was trying to extrude that face.

Then I've seen something just now, that problem (that i've described up here) happens when I click on <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude a face then cancel with right click, then try to move it with <kbd>G</kbd> right after...

Also, I've noticed that when I do that (<kbd>E</kbd>), then cancel with right click, an edge seems to be created.

I'm not really clear here I think...so I've made a video, these are the steps I've done in this video:

1. Move face with <kbd>G</kbd>
2. Extrude with <kbd>E</kbd> then cancel with right click
3. Try to move again with <kbd>G</kbd> (not working like the first time)
4. Dissolve an edge (yeah I should dissolve the 4 edges of the face, but we still see the effect)
5. Move face with <kbd>G</kbd>

--------------> Video link here: https://youtu.be/8NPMJdZDQro

Can maybe someone explain me why it's acting like this?
Is it normal? And if yes, is there some reason to that (technical or functional)?

Thanks a lot to everyone :)

Comment: Yes extruding and right click make a new face

Comment: If you want to be sure about this you can check number of faces at (top - right) corner of Blender3D application

Comment: Thanks @Shamshirsaz.Navid for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome :)